# How to import flow definitions from node_modules

Tags: flowtype, immutable.js

I want to import immutablejs flow type definitions, but I don't want to have my flow server go through everything in node_modules. When it does, the CPU jumps to 100% and it takes forever to do anything. I have added node_modules as and ignore in flowconfig, but then immutablejs module is not being recognised. What can I do about it? My flowconfig:

```
[ignore]
.happypack/.*
.*node_modules/.

[include]

[libs]
flow-typed

[lints]

[options]
esproposal.class_static_fields=enable
esproposal.class_instance_fields=enable
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you need to update the flowconfig file. ImmutableJS library already contains Flow type definitions.

For example to import Map type definition do :

`import type { Map } from 'immutable'`

in the file where you going to use it.